# how to change input type with onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, toggle

I have a check box and a text box in same row. Initially the type of the text box will be hidden, When I click the check box the type of the text box should change from hidden to text. if I unchecked it should change from type text to hidden. How can I do this? here is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Customer_Web" value="yes" style="float:left;">  <h4 align="left" style="font-size:16px; margin-left:20px !important;">Web Designing</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="Web_Designing_Details" placeholder="Web Designing Details" class="form-control input-md" >

                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please try something yourself first and show that... This is not a free coding site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of text box from hidden to text.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="Web_Designing_Details" placeholder="Web Designing Details" class="form-control input-md hidden" >
```

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $('input[name=Web_Designing_Details]').hide();

  $('input[name=Customer_Web]').change(function(){

    if( $(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      $('input[name=Web_Designing_Details]').hide();
    }  
    else
    {
      $('input[name=Web_Designing_Details]').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the type of `input` you are probably looking for visibility of input type `text`, you can set display to none or block or use jQuery method show and hide.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pebq76zm/)

```
$('.row :checkbox').change(function(){    
    $('.form-control.input-md')[0].style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hidden the input (don't care about the type), you can use `toggleClass` as below:

```
$('YOUR_INPUT').toggleClass('hidden', $('YOUR_CHECKBOX').is(':checked'));
```

Comment: You don't have to declare the 'hidden' class rule. He is using bootstrap, which already has it defined. Just a FYI

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to show and hide it depending on state of checkbox

- `$('#nameOfElement').show();`
- `$('#nameOfElement').hide();`